# How do catalog_product_entity and core_store join?

Tags: product, attributes, database, stores

I'm doing some database scripting and found that `catalog_product_entity` does not contain a `store_id` column, although other associated tables such as `catalog_product_entity_varchar` do.

My understanding is that products are not shared across stores, so the product itself should be joinable to `core_store`.  Which tables and columns are used to enforce this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A product is associated to a website via `catalog_product_website`.

A product has a lot of attributes (which are extendable) and can have different scopes, which means you can have different values for the different websites/storeviews.

There are a few attributes for a product which are static and therefore in global scope, this means they are a column in `catalog_product_entity` and the same for all scopes (storeviews/websites). e.g. `sku`.

That said to answer the question:
There is no table or relationship which is used for a direct connection between a product and a store.